# Totally disconnected is a topological invariant, but not a continuous invariant

Tags: general-topology

I am self-learning topology and would like help with the following exercise.

Prove: The property of being totally disconnected is a topological invariant but not a continuous invariant.

I can prove that being totally disconnected is a topological invariant because any homeomorphism induces a one-to-one correspondence between components. Thus let $f: X \to Y$ be a homeomorphism and let $X$ be totally disconnected. Each component of $X$ maps to a distinct component of $Y$. Since the components of $X$ are singletons, so are the components of $Y$. Hence $Y$ is totally disconnected.

To complete the proof, I believe that I must furnish an example of a continuous surjection $f : X \to Y$ that does not preserve the property of being totally disconnected. Moreover, $f$ should not be a homeomorphism. Thus either $f$ is not bijective or $f^{-1}$ is not continuous.

Can anyone provide me with an appropriate example or a hint please?

Comment: Hint. A good one is the "binary" map from $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$ to $[0,1]$

Comment: Hint: any space is the continuous image of a discrete space.

Comment: @GEdgar thank your for the hint! What is the "binary map"? When I search Google for binary map of sequences to the unit interval I found material on the dyadic transformation (bit shift map), but it was not totally clear how I could use it. If it is easy to expand on what you mean, I would appreciate it.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma thanks! I believe that I used your hint to produce an example that is sufficient for completing the exercise.

Comment: Binary map:  sequence of 0s and 1s maps to the real number whose binary expansion (right of the point) is those 0s and 1s .  In this example, both spaces are compact separable metric.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T})$ be the real line with the discrete topology and let $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}')$ be the real line with the usual topology. Let $f$ be any surjective function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Since any discrete topological space is totally disconnected, so is $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T})$. However the real line with the usual topology is not totally disconnected. Moreover since any function on a discrete topological space is continuous, $f$ is an example of a continuous surjection from a space that is totally disconnected to a space that is not totally disconnected, which shows that the property of being totally disconnected is not a continuous invariant.

Comment: Simplify: just use $f(x)=x$ which clearly fits the bill.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma yes I had chosen $f(x) = x$, however I then realized that any surjective function $f$ would work. In general, I have a preference for being concrete when it comes to examples, so I guess there really was no reason not to go with $f(x) = x$.

Comment: Indeed. An example should (IMO) always be as concrete as possible..